# ZF3 form element classes get encoded with unicode entities

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-framework3

I'm trying to figure out why ZF3 encodes my element's class string, but can't find anything about that behaviour on the internet.

```
$this->add([
    'type'  => 'Button',
    'name' => 'submitLogin',
    'options' => [
        'label' => '<i class="zmdi zmdi-check"></i>',
        'label_options' => [
            'disable_html_escape' => true,
        ]
    ],
    'attributes' => [
        'type' => 'submit',
        'class' => 'btn btn--icon login__block__btn',
    ],
]);
```

becomes

```
<button type="submit" name="submitLogin" class="btn&#x20;btn--icon&#x20;login__block__btn" value=""><i class="zmdi zmdi-check"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an abstract concept. Generally we take some steps when we work with data. **We filter input values and escape outputs**. This is a security philosophy.

Zend Framework did the same thing while something is about security. This means this behavior is by default. ZF escapes attributes' values when it is being displayed onto the browser. ZF only allows non-escaping through explicit options like you did for the `label`'s content above.

You will get some concept via [this issue](https://github.com/zendframework/zendframework/issues/3015) on github where [Matthew](https://github.com/zendframework/zendframework/issues/3015#issuecomment-21340543) said:

> Secure by default is the mantra